# date doesn't accept its own output

Tags: shell, ssh, quoting, date

What is the option for `date` to give output in a format acceptable to `date --set` ?

I'm trying to remotely set the date, using the current computer clock of my workstation.

```
ssh user@host sudo date --set="`date`"
```

and

```
ssh user@host sudo date --set="`date -R`"
```

both give "extra operand" and "invalid option" errors.

Yes, I know I can type `--set="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"`, but the computer should be able to do that for me.

Answer (score 1):

`date` does accept its output, if quoted.  Sending quotes through ssh needs escaping.

This works:

```
ssh user@host sudo date --set="\"`date -R`\""
```

Some systems might not accept the above, but will accept

```
ssh user@host sudo date -u --set="\"`date -u +"%Y.%m.%d-%T"`\""
```

Comment: @slm: I think the quotes will still be eaten by my workstation shell and not go through ssh